# Intellij IDEA pluggin cannot be run

Tags: java, exception, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am new to Intellij plugin development. Currently I am working on a project in creating a plugin to Intellij IDEA. When I click on the run button, it builds successfully and shows me the first window of the new IDEA but when I click on Open new project it gives me these errors and exceptions.

```
[  20681]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - null 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.ModuleBuilder.getModuleTypeName(ModuleBuilder.java:384)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.ModuleBuilder.getPresentableName(ModuleBuilder.java:380)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.newProjectWizard.TemplatesGroup.<init>(TemplatesGroup.java:61)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectWizard.ProjectTypeStep.fillTemplatesMap(ProjectTypeStep.java:298)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectWizard.ProjectTypeStep.<init>(ProjectTypeStep.java:136)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectWizard.NewProjectWizard.init(NewProjectWizard.java:50)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectWizard.NewProjectWizard.<init>(NewProjectWizard.java:39)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.NewProjectAction.actionPerformed(NewProjectAction.java:30)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.ActionLink$1.linkSelected(ActionLink.java:64)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel.doClick(LinkLabel.java:106)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.ActionLink.doClick(ActionLink.java:77)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel$MyMouseHandler.mouseReleased(LinkLabel.java:277)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:565)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
[  20694]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.2  Build #IC-141.713.2 
[  20694]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_25 
[  20695]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
[  20695]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
[  20695]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Windows 8.1 
[  20696]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action:  
[  28044]   WARN - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Watcher terminated with exit code 0 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=250m; support was removed in 8.0
```

Please help me to get out of this and run my plugin if anyone has any idea.. thanks...

Comment: You've got a null pointer exception

Comment: yes I understand but what is this  
    llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager

Comment: @PrasadLakmal this means you have registered something incorrect and corrupted an internal data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem I just uninstalled and re installed the Intellij IDEA and reopened the project. This solved my problem.